# Toggle add and remove class in JavaScript with if condition

Tags: javascript

I have a element with an id="caretToggle" and a button with onclick="caretToggle()". This fires a function that adds a class to invert the caret on the button.

I am successful in running:

```
function caretToggle() {
  var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggle");
  caretElement.classList.add("dropup");
}
```

But This leaves the caret inverted after the collapse is closed. I want to toggle the caret once the button is clicked again.

This is my condition code that I have failed to get working:

```
function caretToggle() {
  var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggle");
  if (caretElement.classList.contains("dropup")) {
    caretElement.classList.remove("dropup");
  } else {
    caretElement.classList.add("dropup");
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide!

Comment: @gooosegoose this should be working. Could you please share MVP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to check wheter contains or not.
What you can do simply use `toggle` function on `classList` :)

```js
function caretToggle() {
  var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggle");
  caretElement.classList.toggle("dropup");
}
```

And also there is a conditional toggle like:

`caretElement.classList.toggle("dropup", counter < 10)`

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)  from MDN

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle class simply do it like this

```js
let caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggle");
    function caretToggle() {
      caretElement.classList.toggle("dropup");
      console.log('class attribute contains: ', caretElement.className)
    }
```

```css
span {
margin:10px;
}


.dropup {
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span id="caretToggle">HTMLElement</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="caretToggle()">Click</button>
```